# Dojo Date text box and history.back() function

Tags: dojo

Here is the flow:-

page:-1 select Date from dojo DateTextBox and submit the page. There are couple of text fields along with date text box.

page2:- Review the values submitted in Page1. Have a option to go back using javascript History.back()

Problem:- when I go back other text boxes preserve their values but dojo DateTextField not able to prepopulate  with the original value.

How I make the dojo component to remember its value when History.back() gets called?

I know History.back() function render the page from browser cache.

Thanks,
Manoj

Answer (score 0):

The text boxes are remembering their values as a feature of the browser. The Dijit won't do this because the browser doesn't know anything about it. You would have to write custom code and remember the setting via a cookie and set the widget to the value of the cookie on page load (or on widget instantiation).